# Why can not run React onLoad on img?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to do when images are loaded loadImg1 variable is false;
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
const [loadImg1, setLoadImg1] = useState(true);

{
  Array.isArray(data) &&
    data.map((value, index) => (
      <img
        key={index}
        className={cls(count == index ? css.avatar : css.noFoto)}
        src={value.photoUrl}
        loading={`${index === 0 ? "eager" : "lazy"}`}
        onLoad={setLoadImg1(false)}
      />
    ));
}
```

Comment: Should be `() => setLoadImg1(false)` otherwise you are immediately calling it.

Comment: Can you try like, ```onLoad ={ () => { setLoadImg1(false) } } ```??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you have to give function definition for events like **`onLoad={()=>setLoadImg1(false)}`** .  As per your current code `onLoad={setLoadImg1(false)}` , it will execute `setLoadImg1(false)` at the time of component rendering instead of after image get loaded  and when your image actually get loaded, **onLoad** event will not find any function to execute.

```
const [loadImg1, setLoadImg1] = useState(true);

{
  Array.isArray(data) &&
    data.map((value, index) => (
      <img
        key={index}
        className={cls(count == index ? css.avatar : css.noFoto)}
        src={value.photoUrl}
        loading={`${index === 0 ? "eager" : "lazy"}`}
        onLoad={()=>setLoadImg1(false)}
      />
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the people said earlier in comments. There is a major difference in using `setLoadImg1(false)` over `() => setLoadImg1(false)`.

### What is the difference exactly?

When you use something like `setLoadImg1(false)` and pass it as a prop to one of your components React automatically will run this during the **first-page load no matter the `onLoad` event happened or not**, in the other hand when the `onLoad` event going to happen it will be executed one more time (and it does not make sense since its just executed one time before it and the `loadImg1` has been set to `false` already), so we have at least two rerender here.

But when you use the **function definition** instead like this `() => setLoadImg1(false)` it will only trigger when the `onLoad` event fires.

So the final output should be something like this:

```js
const [loadImg1, setLoadImg1] = useState(true);

{
  Array.isArray(data) &&
    data.map((value, index) => (
      <img
        key={index}
        className={cls(count == index ? css.avatar : css.noFoto)}
        src={value.photoUrl}
        loading={`${index === 0 ? "eager" : "lazy"}`}
        onLoad={()=>setLoadImg1(false)}
      />
    ));
}
```